# Camel delete zip file after processed

Tags: apache-camel

I face a requirement. Monitor incoming zip file in folder, unzip it, and copy content of zip in some other folder. I have implemented the function with Camel DSL. Now I have a extra requirement that delete the zip file after processed. I put noop=true in DSL. So the source zip file cannot be deleted or moved. 
How can I implement the extra requirement?

Comment: There is a delete option on the file component

Comment: If I add delete=true option in, camel will throw exception. I think during the processing the source zip file cannot be deleted.

Comment: Check your code you may need to close some input stream and other resources that lock the source file. Typically problem on Window where as linux works better.

Comment: Yes, the zip file seems to be locked by windows, coz I'm not able to delete the file in Windows system using delete key. But some time passing, the lock is released, then I could.